# Conventions for FX Options

Tags: fx, delta, convention

I am looking for conventions (delta, atm, premium adjusted) related to FX Options. For popular currency pairs (e.g. USD EUR) they should be found in Ian Clark's Foreign Exchange Option Pricing. But what about more exotic ones like USD RMB? Can those conventions be found somewhere (except from bloomberg), or do I have to make a more or less educated guess?

Comment: I do not know of an exhaustive list, but generally all currencies are premium adjusted, except where USD is not CCY1. It will always be ATM DNS (delta neutral straddle), with some exceptions for >10y being ATMF. Always best to simply ask your data provider what they use. Even if spot is USDCHF by convention, swiss retail banks frequently quote CHFUSD for example.

Comment: I have found that different brokers have different conventions, so you really do need to contact your data vendor to know which to use I'm afraid.